# Как устранить ошибку undefined method при .create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Всем привет, прохожу курс Rails for Zombies 2. Я делаю всё как в видео, но у меня всё равно ошибка. Я не могу создать нового зомби.
Когда ввожу:

```
z = Zombie.create
```

появляется вот такая ошибка:

```
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
        from /home/basania/RubymineProjects/Tweeter/app/models/zombie.rb:9:in `make_rotting'
        from /home/basania/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
        from /home/basania/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `call'
        from
```

и так далее, лог довольно большой. Вот код в модели `Zombie`:

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :rotting, -> { where(rotting: true) }
  scope :fresh, -> { where('age < 20') }
  scope :recent, -> { order('created_at desc').limits(3) }
  has_one :brain
  before_save :make_rotting
  def make_rotting
      self.rotting = true if age > 20
  end
end
```

Код контроллера `ZombiesController`:

```
def update
    @zombie = Zombie.find(params[:id]) #Эту строка добавлялась
    respond_to do |format| #...
// ...
// создавалось скафолдом, там все методы CRUD
end
```

и контроллер `RottingController`:

```
class RottingZombiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  @rotting_zombies = Zombie.rotting
  end
end
```

Прошу прощения за громоздкость, если надо будет ещё какой-то код, я ещё скину сюда. Если можно, помогите в скайпе: carlson444.

Comment: Похоже, что `age` пустой.

Comment: @Nakilon куда его прописать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, что у Вас в миграции не устанавливается значение по умолчанию для поля :age. Следовательно,

```
before_save make_rotting
```

пытается обработать условие:

```
nil > 20
```

Выходов из этой ситуации несколько:

1) Повесить условие на `make_rotting`:

```
before_save make_rotting, if: :age?
```

2) Добавить миграцию:

```
class SetDefaultAgeToZombies < ActiveRecord::Migration  
  def change  
    change_column :zombies, :age, :integer, default: 0  
  end  
end
```

P.S. И проверьте код по курсу. Вряд ли авторы могли оставить такую ошибку.
Или же код курса не предполагает создание записи без указания age.